# C++: Remove object without calling destructor

Tags: c++, c++17, destructor, c++pmr

For those unfamiliar with polymorphic memory resources (PMR),

[std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource):

> "the class `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource` is a special-purpose memory resource class that releases the allocated memory only when the resource is destroyed. It is intended for very fast memory allocations in situations where memory is used to build up a few objects and then is released all at once."

As such, if the only purpose of the destructor is to release memory, there is no point in calling it on a monotonic buffer resource:

```cpp
auto mbr = std::make_unique<std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource>();

auto vectors = std::pmr::vector<std::pmr::vector<int>>(mbr.get());
vectors.resize(1'000'000, pmr_vector<int>(100));  // Create 1M vectors with 100 ints each

// Reset vectors
// This will cause 1M destructors to be unnecessarily called
vectors = {};
```

As all memory is drawn from `mbr`, I would like to simply destroy the buffer. That however, will not prevent `vectors`' destructor from being called and trying to deallocate memory that has already been freed.

A really, really bad way to do this is to call `std::memset(&vectors, 0, sizeof(vectors));`. This improves the performance by 2.8x, but the comments to the (now deleted) answer strongly agree that this should not be done.

Because the standard libraries do not fully support PMR yet, I provided a **complete example** based on boost here: https://godbolt.org/z/nMbbez - it requires -lboost_container

Comment: I am not convinced that the call to the 1M destructors is "unnecessary"

Comment: From a language standpoint, you are right. From an execution standpoint, they don't make a difference, which is why I called them "unnecessary". Once the MBR is deleted, they are gone one way or the other. This would be different if the vectors stored a non-trivially destructible type.

Comment: to be honest, the concept sounds like opposite of flyweight pattern while having purpose of flyweight, while it is flyweight that should be used in such case.

Comment: Calling the destructors is not the problem but what the destructor does. A destructor not only frees memory but might also end the lifetime of managed objects. I don’t know `pmr`, but it sounds like you need to change the allocator for the container.

Comment: is your performance measurement done with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @t.niese That sounds like a good idea. To make sure that I understand you correctly, you suggest a modified `polymorphic_allocator` where `deallocate` is a no-op, correct?

Comment: @bolov - Argh. Not for the numbers that I originally posted, but for the case that brought me here. With `-O3`, the memset version is still 2.8x faster. Updated.

Comment: `vectors.resize(1'000'000, {100});  // Create 1M vectors with 100 ints each` are you sure this is what is done here? It is more like 1M of vectors containing single value `100`.

Comment: @MarekR: You are right. I hate that constructor. It doesn't make a difference for the question though.

Comment: No, as I said, I don't know `pmr`, and I don't know your exact use case. But preallocated/manually pooled memory does not mean you get rid of all memory management, but instead of doing multiple memory allocation requests to the OS - which can be expensive - you allocate larger chunks that are managed by your application. But you still need to keep track of which part of that memory is used and which one isn't anymore. So in case of nested vectors with dynamic size destruction is likely never a noop.

Comment: Where is std::pmr::vector from?

Comment: It was introduced in C++17, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*t.niese* had a great suggestion in the comments, which was to change the allocator of the containers. After all, our issue is not with the container, but that the allocator thinks that it needs to call `do_deallocate`. We can simply copy the code of boost's `polymorphic_allocator` and replace `deallocate` with a no-op. You can find the entire code [here](https://gist.github.com/mrks/c868288708a72ab9c2af936796ed3ba3). In the end, it is just copied from [polymorphic_allocator.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/container/pmr/polymorphic_allocator.hpp) with `deallocate` replaced like this:

```cpp
  void deallocate(T* p, size_t n) noexcept {}
```

We can verify that this works by using a printing memory resource (see the [debug_resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683240/how-the-synchronized-pool-resource-actually-works) here or the one in the gist linked above). If we allocate 3 inner vectors of 100 entries each using the original polymorphic_allocator, we see

```cpp
my_vector<my_vector<int>> vectors{mbr.get()};
vectors.resize(3, my_vector<int>(100));
// malloc 96
// malloc 400
// malloc 400
// malloc 400
// free 400
// free 400
// free 400
// free 96
```

Note that we did not need to pass `mbr` into the inner vector. This is done [automatically by PMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654606/c-cant-propagate-polymorphic-allocator-with-scoped-allocator-adaptor). With our new `no_free_allocator`, the result is only

```
// malloc 96
// malloc 400
// malloc 400
// malloc 400
```

As expected, the memory is not freed anymore, but the objects are still properly deconstructed. Let us look at how this changes the performance of the deconstruction. The entire benchmark is also contained in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrks/c868288708a72ab9c2af936796ed3ba3). Note that I changed the size of the inner vectors and preallocated memory for the `monotonic_buffer_resource`. This is to make the effects more pronounced and to highlight the benefits of PMR and MBR in particular. Here are the results (`g++10 -O3`):

|  | polymorphic_allocator | no_free_allocator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| resize w/ default_resource | 47910 | 62574 |
| resize w/ monotonic_buffer_resource | 30298 | 30947 |
| reset w/ default_resource | 12298 | 3 (but leaks) |
| reset w/ monotonic_buffer_resource | 5463 | 2520 |

First, this proves the initial motivation of using a `monotonic_buffer_resource`. You can see that the resize is much faster if we do not call `malloc` for each vector. I am still unsure why the `no_free_allocator` is slower than the `polymorphic_allocator` if no MBR is used, but that is a different topic.

Second, by removing the virtual method calls to `do_deallocate`, we reduce the cost of resetting the outer vector and the MBR by just over 50%. The remaining cost of 2520 us is caused by having to free the MBR, not by resetting the vectors.

Compared to `std::allocator` (which takes 58087 us to resize and 10741 us to reset), this takes is roughly twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with polymorphic containers and allocators but I suspect that the problem is that all those vectors use different allocators. Just your main one uses your `mbr`. So you really have 1000001 different pools. Not what you intended I think.

So try this:

```
// vectors of 1 element each as your actual code (see note bellow)
vectors.resize(1000000, pmr_vector<int>(1, 100, mbr.get())); 

// or
// vectors of 100 elements each as your comment (see note bellow)
vectors.resize(1000000, pmr_vector<int>(100, 0, mbr.get()));
```

This does the same thing, except that all the 100001 vectors now share the same `monotonic_buffer_resource`. And now you use just one pool that is released when you "reset" the `mbr.

---

Note: your comment is wrong. `vectors.resize(1'000'000, {100});` creates `1'000'000` vectors with 1 element of value `100` each.

Comment: PMR/MBR works slightly differently. The allocator that is passed into the outer vector is implicitly propagated into the inner vector. The original code already uses the same MBR for all inner vectors. As such, their de-allocation already is a no-op, but it still requires a virtual method call. This is because the polymorphic_allocator *could* also point to a different memory resource whose `do_deallocate` method is not a no-op.

Comment: @mrks I think you are wrong. The allocator is copied when you copy a vector. But in this case you create new vectors. The new vectors don't have any relation with the original vector and do not share the allocator.

Comment: Here is an example that shows how the memory_resource is implicitly passed down: https://godbolt.org/z/n1rzrW. It returns 320/400/400/..., showing that the test_resource is used for both the outer and the inner containers. See also this older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654606/c-cant-propagate-polymorphic-allocator-with-scoped-allocator-adaptor

Comment: I still think you are wrong. But I can't investigate further now. I will come back later to this.